Is the MSE of a strictly monotone continuous function quasiconvex?
The MSE function of one parameter $a$ is defined as:
$$\text{MSE}(a) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\left( f(x_i;a)-y_i \right)^2,$$
The statement is that if the function $f(x_i;a)$ is continuous and strictly monotone in $a$, then the function $\text{MSE}(a)$ is quasiconvex. It is possible to show that each term in the sum satisfies the second order condition for quasiconvexity and is therefore quasiconvex, but is the sum of two terms quasiconvex? In the paper ABOUT THE SUM OF QUASICONVEX FUNCTIONS give here
https://repositorio.up.edu.pe/bitstream/handle/11354/1881/DD1707.pdf?sequence=1
there are conditions for the sum of two quasiconvex functions being quasiconvex, do they apply here ? this is just a possible direction to prove or disprove this statement

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.
